# jQuery Check if animate left is greater than 1000px

Tags: jquery, animation, move

I bet this will be easy one but I've been looking for an answer for two days straight (I'm not really into programming).
How can I trigger an event (in my case this would be addClass event) in jQuery after a certain element reaches or passes `animate({left: "1000px"})`.

```
   $(".arrow-right").click(function(){
        $(".portfolio-row").animate({
            right: "+=500px"}, 500
        );
    });
```

This code above moves the div `.portfolio-row` 500px right each time the `.arrow-right` is pressed. Now I want to add a class "hide" to `.arrow-right` when `.portfolio-row` is moved for more than 1000px.

I'm a beginner, really. :D

Comment: You can use a global variable `x` that is initiated at 0, and incremented or decremented  based on right or left arrow is clicked and inside your code include a line to hide the left arrow if  `x` is <= `-2` and hide the right arrow if `x` is >= `2`, else show both arrows

Comment: I knew this will be easy. Thanks. I focused to reuse data from the animate function so much that I didn't see the easiest approach. :D